# MVC session state can i disable in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In IIS setting may I disable Session state without issue?

Answer (score 6):

Only if you're not using it.

Comment: The funniest part is that it's true. If you want people to be able to give you a more useful answer, you'll need to tell a bit more about your application. The specific question we'd like to find out the answer for is, "do you store anything in the session".

Comment: perhaps a poor question but being as it is obvious I am not explicitly using session, I presumed an intuitive response from the intellengent community in the sense that is there something  mvc does with session that is not obvious to user. i guess I am a bit presumptuous.

Answer (score 1):

@zsharp, i don't believe mvc is doing anything with session no so there should be no reason why you can't simply turn it off.

The question i have is if you're not using it do you need to turn it off in the first place?

even if someone were to inject something into the session, if you're not using it then can it hurt?

I guess what i'm asking is there are particular reason why you want to switch it off?

Comment: I guess it's some sort of ocd compelling me to do stuff like that. If there is no potential negative effects in leaving it as is I suppose i would.

Comment: Yeah I'd leave it alone.  If it aint broke then don't fix it! :)